# Scala path-dependent types: type from reference to member val object seems to be different that type coming directly from original val object?

Tags: scala

My title is probably not really describing the problem real well.  I do not need the answer to this question for what I am doing, I have things correct now, but while I was working with the Scala combinator parsers I had this issue that confused me.  I would like to understand the language better (I'm a Scala newbie for the most part), so I thought I would see if anyone can explain this to me:

Here is the code:

```
package my.example

import scala.io.Source
import scala.util.parsing.input.StreamReader
import scala.util.parsing.combinator.lexical.StdLexical
import scala.util.parsing.combinator.syntactical.StandardTokenParsers

class DummyParser extends StandardTokenParsers
{
    def scan
    (
        filename : String
    ) : Unit =
    {
        // Read in file
        val input = StreamReader( Source.fromFile( filename ).bufferedReader )
        // I want a reference to lexical in StandardTokenParsers
        val mylexical = lexical
        // Even if I put a type above like these two below it does not help
        // val mylexical : StdLexical = lexical
        // val mylexical : Tokens = lexical
        val tokensGood : lexical.Scanner = new lexical.Scanner( input )
        /*
        Compile error in following line:
        error: type mismatch;
        found   : mylexical.Scanner
        required: DummyParser.this.lexical.Scanner
        */
        val tokensBad : lexical.Scanner = new mylexical.Scanner( input )
    }
}
```

The "val tokensBad" line gets the compile error shown in the comments.  Isn't mylexical above referencing the exact same object as this.lexical (defined in StandardTokenParsers that the class above is deriving from).  Reading "Programming in Scala" I think I sort of understand that the type of lexical.Scanner is path dependent (Section 20.7), but shouldn't lexical.Scanner and mylexical.Scanner be the same type?  Isn't lexical and mylexical the same object?  Heck, the dog food example in the book on page 426 seems to say the SuitableFood type from two different dogs is the same, and in my case above its the exact same object (I think).  What's really going on here?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You would like the compiler to consider `lexical.Scanner` and `mylexical.Scanner` as equal, based on the fact that at runtime, the value of `mylexical` and `lexical` is always the same. This is a run-time property, and the type checker doesn't do any data-flow analysis (that would be way too slow to be practical).

So you need to help the type checker by telling it that the two values are always the same. You can do that by using a `singleton type`. A singleton type is a type that has exactly one value, and is written as (in this case) `lexical.type`.

If you change the definition of `mylexical` to:

```
val mylexical: lexical.type = lexical
```

your program type-checks.

What we just did is tell the type checker that `mylexical` can only have one value at runtime, given by the singleton type.

Comment: Thank you Iulian Dragos for your reply.  I read your response but I still was not getting it at first. I made your change and it corrected the compile error, but I was not sure why at first. I had tried things like "val mylexical : StdLexical = lexical" which I would have thought would have been the same as lexical.type, but they did not work.  However, I re-read section 20.7 in the book with your reply in mind and then things clicked.

Comment: With the dog food example in the book, the SuitableFood type is just an alias for a normal outer class.  So the SuitableFood types from different dogs are compatible.  However, I then studied the Outer/Inner example that immediately follows.  In that case o1.Inner is not compatible with o2.Inner.  In my original question, lexical.Scanner is an inner class, so it is like this example, not the dog food example.  Your comment about the type checker not doing data-flow analysis now makes sense to me in this light.  I think I now have a general idea of what is going on thanks to your reply.

Comment: Glad it helped. I can edit the answer to make it clearer, if you tell me what was the missing piece in the puzzle. The fact that the type  `SdtLexical` and `lexical.type` are different?